# How to set quantity 1 for some products?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

I have created one attribute and based on that attribute, I have set quantity `1` to few products. But now my issue is that, when I add few products twice then its amount gets calculated.

How to avoid such scenarios ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Response according to what I understood:

You don't need to create attribute for this requirement. Default magento(Magento1 and magento2) provides attribute `Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart` and you just need to set `1` here so customer can only add only `1` product.

You can see this option by edit any product and go to `advanced Inventory section`.

Thanks